# Change first focus of QLineEdit elements

Tags: c++, qt

I just created my first simple QT app. I used some QLineEdit´s and messed up the order so the first one created isn´t the first visible one. But because it is the first created one it is in focus after starting the app. Is there a simple way to fix this?